# TFS Custom Build Process Template Errors - Cannot view designer

Tags: tfs, build-process

I'm getting a bunch of errors about missing references. Anyone know why?

[image]

Viewing the default template does the same thing. Reloading the designer does not work. I have TFS Power Tools installed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. You need the full version of VS2010 installed. Not just the Team Explorer.